# Anyway to tell iCloud Drive in Sierra to stop downloading things?

Tags: icloud, finder, hard-drive

With macOS Sierra's iCloud Drive feature, it seems the promise of automatic space management is that:

1. it will fill your hard drive's free space by downloaing iCloud drive files automatically
2. it only clears the local copies when you select other iCloud drive files to download instead

This works to keep your HDD constantly full to capacity, causing many issues with other programs, including Terminal and iTunes complaining there is not enough free space to continue. Despite Finder reporting there is plenty (due to point 2).

Is there a way to tell iCloud  Drive to stop attempting to download more files (fixing point 1), and to delete the local copies of files it has insisted on downloading (fixing point 2)?

---

The below image captures the problem. Finder reports 157.99GB available, yet I can't download a 773.1MB folder because there isn't enough free space, because iCloud Drive is insisting on filling my hard drive with 164.63GB of data.

[image: Image capture of the problem]

Comment: Has anyone seen anything different with High Sierra? I'm experiencing the same as your question. iCloud Drive turned on, taking up 120+GB and 10GB of storage space left.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you call [this script](https://github.com/balupton/dotfiles/blob/7e9c0ebe05bec4c70478ad2c55043c028f65d994/.scripts/commands/cloudevict) using:

```
find "$HOME/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" -exec cloudevict {} \;
```

it in theory will delete the local copies of everything, which seems to work more or less, however as soon as it is done, iCloud Drive will attempt to fill your hard drive once again, and there still seems to be absolutely no way to stop it.